# highcharts scatter change point color

Tags: javascript, highcharts

How can I change the color of scatter plot point at click? 
I can't find the proper solution to this based on this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Uu9ck/1/)
My problem is that I when I capture the click event, I can't find the proper place for the `fillColor` property of the point.

```
$(function () {
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            type: 'scatter'
        },
        series: [{
          data: [194.1, 95.6, {y:54.4,fillColor:'#FF0000'}]
        }]
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this should do

```
plotOptions: {
  series: {
    cursor: 'pointer',
    point: {
      events: {
        click: function() {
          var pt = this.options;
          pt.fillColor = 'black';
          this.update(pt, true);
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here is the updated [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/Uu9ck/77/).

Comment: Great! I changed yours to this.update() and it asks for parameters. I believe it's those? http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Point.update

Comment: One more: how can I adjust the marker size per specific point? Any idea?

Comment: just add `pt.radius = 10;`